# What's the RGB Color For the Windows COLOR_WINDOW or COLOR_BACKGROUND?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, colors, rgb

In the Windows Api and GDI, you can use the default window background color for drawing buttons and stuff (that slight greyish color on Win98 , WinXP + Classic Theme etc. ).

What is the rgb value for that?

So I can emulate the exact color in Allegro using `al_map_rgb( r, g, b)` ?

Comment: umm.. just out of curiosity, why the close vote?

Comment: The close vote is for "off topic".  I think the question does initially _appear_ to be off-topic, as it's about user-visible parts of the Windows UI and what color they are, which is not directly programming.  However, I think the accepted answer is unquestionably a "programming" answer, and makes it clear that in context this is a programming question and should not be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the users settings.

You should use [GetSysColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to retrieve the DWORD value and then use `GetRValue`, `GetGValue`, and `GetBValue` to retrieve red, green and blue component values.

Answer (score 7):

Although Bobrovsky's answer (use GetSysColor) is likely the right solution to the actual problem, if you want to know the default warm gray color regardless of the user's settings, it's R=212, G=208, B=200.

(The simple way to determine this was take a screenshot of a window, paste it into Paint, use the color picker tool on a bit of the default gray, and then open the "edit colors" dialog box to view the RGB values in it.)

Comment: Better still, install [Color Cop](http://colorcop.net/) and directly choose any color on screen..

Comment: Thanks for posting the actual RGB value for those of us who aren't running Windows, so can't just grab a screenshot and use a colour picker.

Comment: #d4d0c8 for those who want the hex code.